# which one of them is the dominant term and what is the big O?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

$3\log_8(n^2)+\log_2(n^3)$

which is the dominant term ? I think that both are dominant as it will become $6 \log_8(n) + 3\log_2(n)$..is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\log_b(x)=\frac{\ln x}{\ln b}$ for all $b>0$, you have
$$ 3\log_8(n^2)+\log_2(n^3)=\left(\frac{6}{\ln 8}+\frac{3}{\ln 2}\right)\ln n $$
None of the terms are dominant (or both).

Comment: and is the big O is O(log n) ?

Comment: Both terms are $\mathcal{O}(\ln n)$.

Comment: and $\log_8(x)=\frac 13 \log_2(x)$ so the first term reduces to $2\cdot\log_2(n)$